# Product symbol, order of multiplication if factors are not commutative?

Tags: notation, products, noncommutative-algebra

Regarding the product notation... if we have non-commutative things (for example matrices):
$$\prod_{i=1}^N {\bf A}_i$$
Is it by default assumed to mean
$${\bf A}_1{\bf A}_2\cdots {\bf A}_N$$
or
$${\bf A}_N{\bf A}_{N-1} \cdots {\bf A}_1$$
or maybe even an arbitrary order?

Comment: the first one. Important that the ring/algebra/whatever be associative

Comment: Also related [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/978338/29335) and its linked question.

Comment: @WillJagy why? I'd say it's $((\dots) A_{n-1})A_n$, that's what comes from the recursive definition of the symbol.